# Error the maximum nesting level exceeded (limit 32) in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to write a procedure which inserts a line so that the nordre value is processed automatically: if there are already n lines with nordre, the new line will have nordre n + 1, otherwise it will have the number 1.

But when I execute my procedure pr_insert_lignes I have this error :

> The maximum nesting level of stored procedures, functions, triggers, or views is exceeded (limit 32).

I use a second procedure pr_getprix which works and recover the value prix for calculate a percentage.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_getprix (@numprod int, @prix money OUTPUT) AS
SELECT @prix = pxunit
FROM produit
WHERE noprod = @numprod
```

And here is my procedure which does the treatment.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_insert_lignes(@nocom int, @noprod int, @nordre int, 
@qtecom int, @pourcentage money) AS DECLARE @prix money 

EXECUTE pr_getprix @noprod, @prix output

if exists (select nordre from ligne)      
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO ligne (nocom, nordre, qtecom, puacc, noprod) VALUES 
     (@nocom, @nordre + 1, @qtecom, @prix*@pourcentage / 100, @noprod) 
END 
ELSE BEGIN
     INSERT INTO ligne (nocom, nordre, qtecom, puacc, noprod) VALUES 
     (@nocom, 1, @qtecom, @prix*@pourcentage / 100, @noprod) 
END



create table PRODUIT
(
Noprod int primary key,
Pxunit smallmoney,
Qtestk int check(Qtestk > 0)
)

create table LIGNE
(
Nocom int,
Nordre int,
Qtecom int,
Puacc smallmoney,
Noprod int,
Montligne as Puacc* Qtecom,
primary key(Nocom, Nordre),
CONSTRAINT FKNOCOM FOREIGN KEY (Nocom) REFERENCES COMMANDE(Nocom),
CONSTRAINT FKNOPROD FOREIGN KEY (Noprod) REFERENCES PRODUIT(Noprod)
)
```

Comment: I don't see the nesting procedures, is this the full code? Check the triggers on involved tables and post their code please.

Comment: Yes it's the full code but I don't have a triggers

Comment: Is `produit` or `ligne` a view or a function? If so, post it's definition please.

Comment: These are my tables. I post her in my question

Comment: I can't see where the nesting is being used. Check database level triggers, maybe there is a problem with one of those. Also, try executing 1 statement at a time (pr_getprix, the inserts, etc.).

Comment: There is no nesting in that.  Even without that error this design is flawed.

Comment: I don't understand this error, however I create a new database and I always have this error

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an MSDN link to point you to but, per SQL Server 2012 unleashed by Ray Rankins , Paul T. Bertucci , Chris Gallelli , Alex T. Silverstein:

`A stored procedure can call itself up to the maximum nesting level of 32`